# Android memory leak example from Google I/O

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I just had a look at the google io video "memory management for android". Slides are available here http://dubroy.com/memory_management_for_android_apps.pdf. The memory leak example is on slide 36.

I do not understand why this causes a leak after orientation change. I do understand that leak is an inner class and has a reference to the outer class. Also, I do understand that the static variable "leak" references the "Leaky" object..thus the whole activity. I think that's special because of the static keyword. Static variables have a certain memory and are probably not gc'ed (at least as long as the application runs)?!?

Well, what happens on oriantation change? A new activity instance is created and the activities `onCreate` is called. `leak == null` is false. Leak still points to the "old" activity. That's a leak. The old activity cant be gc'ed, right?

Why does memory usage increase with every oriantation change? In my (wrong) understanding I'd assume that just the first activity can't be gc'ed. The other activites that are created because of oriantation change can be gc'ed because they aren't referenced by that static variable "leak".

However..obviously..I'm completely wrong!

Comment: Was this useful? An accept would be nice :)

Comment: I think you think that activity destruction == garbage collection. I've added an answer that attempts to explain what's happening. Basically, it's because leak does == null in the newly created activity. For why, read my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A classic explanation of the orientation change Context memory leak from [Google blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). You were most of the way there, I think, noting static reference of the inner to the outer class.

Comment: Yes, I read that before. Its actually the same and the author says "it leaks the first activity". That's the behaviour I described above. It's clear to me that the first activty leaks. But _only_ the first. Oriantation changes after that shouldn't impact/increase the heap anymore respectively no more leaks should occur. But in the video I posted the heap seems to increase with every oriantation change(starts at minute 28) from 9mb to 12 to 15mb. Well, I'm going to test this shortly

Comment: My understanding is that each time you change orientation you lose the activity but it does not get GCd. When you return back to portrait having switched to landscape, you do not get your initial context.

Comment: Yes, you do not get your initial context. But why each time? The static variable only references the first activity

Comment: After the first creation of the activity the static variable is always not null. So the static variable will always refernece the first activity

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand because you made a critical error. leak == null is true in the newly created activity. leak doesn't still point to the "old" activity.

Why? I thought leak was static you ask. Well. . .

So, first time around, the activity is created, leak is null, then onCreate() and leak now references a Leaky object. If I create more instances of that activity, their leak's will not be null and reference that same object.

But, what happens when you flip orientation is that the activity is destroyed. So, there is no existing instance of an activity object. Android then creates a new activity, where leak is null (because as far as Android is concerned, no other instance of the activity exists).

However, to the garbage collector, someone does hold a reference to the destroyed activity, namely its inner Leaky class. So it won't free that memory. Hence, as you continue to change orientation, you keep leaking an activities worth of memory.